# Enabling Loadable Modules Android

Tags: android, kernel

I'm trying to compile a kernel (Goldfish) to later insert some modules. I know that I need to enable module support, module loading, and unloading. I'm using OSX Mavericks.

So far I have checked out goldfish from git, and have done the following:

```
make ARCH=arm goldfish_armv7_defconfig
```

No problems there.  Now when I do:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi- menuconfig
```

I get the following:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf] Error 1
>   make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2

Is there a way that I can enable modules another way? Maybe go into a file and do it manually?

If I just run (which I'm supposed to run after to get a zImage):

```
make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi -j16
```

The kernel compiles and I can run it via an emulator, but obviously I can't upload kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

module loading is disabled by default in android kernel.
Enable it using CONFIG_MODULES=y in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Open scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh

Replace ldflags() with this

```
ldflags()
{
    for ext in so a dylib ; do
        for lib in ncursesw ncurses curses ; do
            #$cc -print-file-name=lib${lib}.${ext} | grep -q /
            #if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            if [ -f /usr/lib/lib${lib}.${ext} ]; then
                echo "-l${lib}"
                exit
            fi
        done
    done
    exit 1
}
```

Now `make menuconfig` should work. The problem seems to be the result of a bug with clang on OS X. The -print-file-name option doesn't work correctly.

Alternatively, you could open .config file in a text editor and set

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check this configuration, go to the kernel source parent directory (**in our example case kernel-common-android13-5.15/kernel/configs/android-5.15**).

Once you are in the “configs” directory you must have to know the config file which is being used by the Android/Emulator build system to build your kernel.
In our example case it is using the file **"android-base.config"**

Search **"CONFIG_MODULES**" string in above file and add add below configuration even by searching CONFIG_MODULES does not find any thing

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
```

For more detail follow my blog
https://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.com/